# sklearn how to mock prediction of zero probabilities of the labels that were not present in the training set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, predict, multiclass-classification

I hope I titled this correctly.

I run a multiclass classification (3 classes). And score it with ROC AUC.

```
make_scorer(roc_auc_score, needs_proba=True, average="macro", multi_class='ovo', labels=[-1, 0, 1])
```

I split the train/test data with a time series splitter and can not reshuffle the order of data (no stratify parameter).

One of the splits does not contain the '0' label in the **train** data. So `.fit` function only sees 2 labels and thus the predict_proba function only has a 2 column output.

I get this ValueError `Number of given labels, 3, not equal to the number of columns in 'y_score', 2` when I run my multiclass ROC AUC scoring.

I thought that I would be ok with the function predicting a zero probability for the case of '0' class. So I want to add a mock probability prediction. Is there any way to do it in the standard library?

Any other recommendations? I thought of 1) wrapping the predict_proba, to add missing probability column 2) changing the time series split so that if train data contains only 2 classes - take more train data.

Comment: I think a simple class that inherits from your trained model and returns a custom `predict_proba` - i.e. with an additional column.

Comment: Yes, had this thought as well. A wrapper function that returns a class with augmented predict_proba. This way it works for all classificators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post what I did eventually. I did a wrapper function that returns a child class of an estimator (eg LogisticRegression) with augmented predict_proba and augmented fit function. The fit function saves which labels it has seen in y_train. the predict_proba function fills with zero the columns corresponding to labels  that were not present in y_train but present in labels.

```
def predict_proba_wrapper(method: classmethod, labels: list):
    """Add zeros to the predict_proba columns if labels not present in y_true."""

    @wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs ):
        # find labels indices not in y_train
        indices_to_fill = []
        for i, label in enumerate(labels):
            if label not in self.labels_seen:
                indices_to_fill.append(i)
        # call method
        y_pred = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # fill zeros
        if not isinstance(y_pred, np.ndarray):
            y_pred_np = np.array(y_pred)
        else:
            y_pred_np = y_pred

        for i in indices_to_fill:
            y_pred_np = np.insert(y_pred_np, i, 0., axis=1)

        if isinstance(y_pred, np.ndarray):
            return y_pred_np
        elif isinstance(y_pred, pd.DataFrame):
            return pd.DataFrame(y_pred_np, index=y_pred.index)
        elif isinstance(y_pred, pd.Series):
            return pd.Series(y_pred_np, index=y_pred.index)
        elif isinstance(y_pred, list):
            return y_pred_np.tolist()
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"y_pred type {type(y_pred)} not supported")

    return wrapper

def fit_wrapper(method: classmethod, labels: list):
    """Add labels seen to the class."""

    @wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs ):
        res = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if len(args) >= 2:
            y = args[1]
        else:
            y = kwargs["y"]
        if isinstance(y, np.ndarray):
            self.labels_seen = list(np.unique(y))
        elif isinstance(y, pd.DataFrame):
            self.labels_seen = list(y.iloc[:, 0].unique())
        elif isinstance(y, pd.Series):
            self.labels_seen = list(y.unique())
        elif isinstance(y, list):
            self.labels_seen = list(set(y))
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"y type {type(y)} not supported")
        if hasattr(self, "classes_"):
            if isinstance(self.classes_, np.ndarray):
                self.classes_ = np.array(labels)
            elif isinstance(self.classes_, pd.DataFrame):
                self.classes_ = pd.DataFrame(labels)
            elif isinstance(self.classes_, pd.Series):
                self.classes_ = pd.Series(labels)
            elif isinstance(self.classes_, list):
                self.classes_ = labels
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"y type {type(y)} not supported")

        return res

    return wrapper


def class_child_with_wrapped_methods(class_: Type, method_names: List[str], wrappers: List[callable]):
    """Return a new class with a method wrapped by method wrapper."""
    new_class = type(class_.__name__ + "Wrapped", (class_,), {})
    for i, method_name in enumerate(method_names):
        setattr(new_class, method_name, wrappers[i](getattr(new_class, method_name)))
    return new_class


def wrap_fit_predict_proba(class_: Type, labels: list):
    """Return a new class with predict_proba wrapped by predict_proba_wrapper."""
    return class_child_with_wrapped_methods(
        class_,
        ["predict_proba", "fit"],
        [
            lambda x: predict_proba_wrapper(x, labels),
            lambda x: fit_wrapper(x, labels)
        ]
    )
    
CLASSIFIERS = [
    wrap_fit_predict_proba(LogisticRegression, labels[-1,0,1]),
    wrap_fit_predict_proba(ExtraTreesClassifier, labels=[-1,0,1]),
]
```